# Mystery of Points in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, geometry, shapes

[image]

I am trying to create a polygon using points in xaml and as per my understanding the output with the given points should be the triangle with black fill, but it return the triangle with pink fill. I am not getting how this is happening. Kindly let me know.

Tha xaml for this is

```
  <Polygon Width="237"
             Height="214"
             Fill="White"
             Stroke="Black"
             StrokeThickness="2">
        <Polygon.Points>
            <Point X="50" Y="50" />
            <Point X="150" Y="150" />
            <Point X="50" Y="150" />

        </Polygon.Points>
    </Polygon>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Point X=0 and Y=0 is in the upper left corner, not in the lower left corner. So the drawing is correct.

To get what you want is to change your xaml as follows:

```
<Polygon Width="237"
         Height="214"
         Fill="Black"
         Stroke="White"
         StrokeThickness="2">
    <Polygon.Points>
        <Point X="50" Y="150" />
        <Point X="150" Y="150" />
        <Point X="150" Y="50" />

    </Polygon.Points>
<Polygon>
```

Answer (score 3):

The point system is the same one used in a `Canvas`, where `0,0` is the top left corner

For example, the point `50,50` is like saying `Canvas.Left="50"` and `Canvas.Top="50"`

To get the shape you want, you need to adjust the points so they read from the top-left instead of the bottom-left.

```
<Polygon Width="237"
         Height="214"
         Fill="White"
         Stroke="Black"
         StrokeThickness="2">
    <Polygon.Points>
        <Point X="50" Y="50" />
        <Point X="150" Y="50" />
        <Point X="150" Y="150" />
    </Polygon.Points>
</Polygon>
```

Comment: Thanks rachel, i've update the image, will you please reverify

Comment: @MSingh Sure, it's updated. To figure out the points you need, just consider the `X` point the `Canvas.Left`, and the `Y` point as the `Canvas.Top`

Answer (score 1):

`<Point X="50" Y="150" />` is wrong location - that's all.

should be: `<Point X="150" Y="50" />`

Simple X Y interchange mistake, there is nothing wrong with your understanding.